# SQL insert row data, trough nulls are not allowed

Tags: sql

I created a simple database in sql 2012 where I didnt allow to store null data, I checked out my program and I see that it still save empty row :( Is there option that can help me prevent save null in db (and why turning off "allow null" didnt stop it?) ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: NULL is not the same thing as "blanks"

Comment: Is there a way to not allow blank record from sql ?

Comment: You should be filtering the input data in the program that reads the input from the user.  Then, insert only 'good' data into the SQL table.  This way, you inform the user that their entry is invalid, and let them try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a [CHECK Constraint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).  This will throw an error when a statement attempts to put data in a field that doesn't match the criteria.

```
ALTER TABLE UserInfo ADD CONSTRAINT CK_UserInfo_Login CHECK (Login <> '')
```

Comment: I solved my problem by modification of my program, thank you for help